# Scala: accessing case class fields when returning a base class after a match statement

Tags: json, scala, playframework, subclass, case-class

I'm currently trying to create a class and subclasses that encapsulate various configuration aspects (provided in json) for a data pipeline; I'm still very much learning scala as well.  I'm using the Play framework library in order to parse the json string input - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaJson

I have some code that currently works, but there are several aspects of it that feel wrong, and this does not feel like the correct approach.

The workflow for the application needs to take a json string, parse and validate it against various similar but slightly different structures, and then make the values accessible for other bits of downstream processing (e.g. if the file type is a csv file, set some config thus, if it's a json file do this instead); but it's important to note that this is a dynamic process.  This seemed to me to be a perfect use case for case classes, but I have a feeling I've misunderstood their use.

So I have a sealed (in order to make sure that all matches are known) abstract class FileConfig, and currently two subclasses, DelimitedConfig and JsonConfig.  The DelimitedConfig class also makes use of an additional case class DelimitedFileTypeDetails, which is essentially the main difference between the two at this point, but there will be other deviations added as I continue; and I also have companion objects for all three classes in order to take advantage of the play framework format method:

```scala
sealed abstract class FileConfig

case class DelimitedFileTypeDetails (delimiter: String, hasColumnHeaders: Boolean, rowsToSkip: Int)

object DelimitedFileTypeDetails {
    implicit val format = Json.format[DelimitedFileTypeDetails]
}

case class DelimitedConfig (deltaLakeDatabricksMountPoint: String,
    restrictedDeltaLakeDatabricksMountPoint: String,
    notebookToRun: String,
    rowHashExclusionColumns: List[String],
    deltaDatabase: String,
    mergeKeySQLClause: String,
    mergeUpdateFilterSQLClause: String,
    fileToMerge: String,
    containsPIIData: Boolean,
    piiEntityNames: List[String],
    transformsClass: String,
    transformsMethod: String,
    extractStartTime: String,
    fileType: String,
    fileTypeDetails: DelimitedFileTypeDetails
    ) extends FileConfig {
      require(fileType == "Delimited", "fileType must be 'Delimited' for class DelimitedConfig")
    }

object DelimitedConfig {
  implicit val format = Json.format[DelimitedConfig]
}

case class JsonConfig (deltaLakeDatabricksMountPoint: String,
    restrictedDeltaLakeDatabricksMountPoint: String,
    notebookToRun: String,
    rowHashExclusionColumns: List[String],
    deltaDatabase: String,
    mergeKeySQLClause: String,
    mergeUpdateFilterSQLClause: String,
    fileToMerge: String,
    containsPIIData: Boolean,
    piiEntityNames: List[String],
    transformsClass: String,
    transformsMethod: String,
    extractStartTime: String,
    fileType: String) extends FileConfig {
      require(fileType == "Json", "fileType must be 'Json' for class JsonConfig")
    }

object JsonConfig {
  implicit val format = Json.format[JsonConfig]
}

object FileConfig {
  implicit val format = Json.format[FileConfig]
}
```

After these I also have a function to then use the play framework's validate method to perform a match against any provided json string; this would be question one - this feels really clunky, and is there a way to amend the nested evaluation of the object?  Essentially it checks to see if it meets the first subclass, and if not (JsError is the result) then check the next and so on:

```scala
object FileConfigParser {

  /**
    * Parse the provided json to ensure it matches the specified format.
    *
    * @param jsonString - a string representation of the json
    * @return - FileConfig of the parsed json
    */
  def parseFileConfig(jsonString: String): FileConfig = {

    val json = Json.parse(jsonString)

    json.validate[DelimitedConfig] match {
      case s: JsSuccess[DelimitedConfig] => s.get.asInstanceOf[DelimitedConfig]
      case e: JsError => {
        json.validate[JsonConfig] match {
          case s: JsSuccess[JsonConfig] => s.get.asInstanceOf[JsonConfig]
          case e: JsError => {
            throw new Error("Invalid json provided")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This all works ok, and when I run the function, the validation is successful; however, with the result of the parseFileConfig function I cannot access the class fields until I run a further match in my main object:-

```scala
val jsonString = """{
      "sourceDatabricksMountPoint": "/mnt/rawlayer/myData/",
      "deltaLakeDatabricksMountPoint": "/mnt/delta/",
      "restrictedDeltaLakeDatabricksMountPoint": "/mnt/sensitive_delta/",
      "notebookToRun":"/Ingestion/LoadDeltaLake",
      "rowHashExclusionColumns": ["RowLastUpdatedTime"],
      "deltaDatabase": "myDb",
      "restrictedDeltaDatabase": "NICE_WFM_RESTRICTED",
      "deltaTableName": "myTable",
      "mergeKeySQLClause": "s.date=t.date AND s.ID=t.ID",
      "mergeUpdateFilterSQLClause":"s.RowHash <> t.RowHash",
      "fileToMerge": "myFile.txt",
      "fileType":"Delimited",
      "fileTypeDetails": {"delimiter": "|",
                          "hasColumnHeaders": true,
                          "rowsToSkip": 1
                              },
      "containsPIIData": true,
      "piiEntityNames": ["name", "surname"],
      "transformsMethod": "convertDateTimeColumns",
      "transformsClass": "com.example.transforms.CustomTransform",
      "extractStartTime":"2020-12-10T00:00:00.000000"
      }"""

    val fileConfig: FileConfig = parseFileConfig(jsonString)

    println(fileConfig.getClass())

    // if you uncomment this it doesn't work
    // println(fileConfig.fileType)

    // but this does work
    val fileType = fileConfig match {
      case d: DelimitedConfig => d.fileType
      case j: JsonConfig => j.fileType
    }

    println(fileType)
```

It feels a little tedious to have to run the match against each field in the main code, is there a way of either doing this within the class, or having the fields accessible from the class?  Or.... am I just doing all this wrong and there's a better way entirely?

Thanks in advance,

Matt

Comment: Just declare the common fields as abstract members of `FileConfig`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every `FileConfig` will have a member of a given type (e.g. `fileType`), you can put that member in `FileConfig`:

```scala
sealed abstract class FileConfig {
  def fileType: String
}
```

and then in the various case classes extending `FileConfig`, you would have `override val fileType: String`.

That said, I'd reconsider having `fileType` be a field in the `case class`es.  If every `DelimitedConfig` will have `fileType` be `"Delimited"`, then it probably makes sense to have that be a `def` and then define a `Format[FileConfig]` which looks at the `fileType` field when deserializing and injects it into the JSON when serializing.  It's been a while since I used Play JSON, so I don't specifically remember the technique there.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it would be something simple; I'd tried adding them as parameters for the abstract class, but not defining them in the abstract.

Not every file will be "Delimited", there will be several more file types to come; json, fixed width and so on

Comment: every `DelimitedConfig` through will be `Delimited`, right?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry yes it will be.